# IAM Role policy for cross account access to S3 bucket in a specific AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Allow access from IAM Role in **AccountA** to given S3 buckets only if they are present in AWS **AccountB** (using Account Number).

Here is my **Role policy** in **AccountA** which currently has following permission. How can I update it to only access S3 bucket in **AccountB**.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::kul-my-bucket/my-dir/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::kul-my-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Wondering if it is possible or should I try it differently?

Is anything similar to this possible for my case by providing the condition in the policy:

```
"Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:accountId": [
                        "111111111111"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I need this because on the S3 bucket in **AccountB** it allows *root* access to **AccountA**. Hence I want to put restriction on Role policy in **AccountA**.

Comment: Do this via a cross-account IAM role. Account B creates a role, assumable from account A or specifically assumable by the IAM user in account A, that permits access to the relevant account B buckets. An admin in account A modifies the account A IAM user's permissions to permit the IAM user to assume that specific IAM role in account B.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @jarmod. This will need an additional role in **Account B**, is it possible to avoid it and do it just with role policy in **Account A**?

Comment: If you modify the trust relationship on the target account A role to include the ARN of the account B IAM user, then you should not need an additional role in account B.

Comment: Thanks, I don't follow it completely right now. So, might reach out if I have any doubt trying it out.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible to grant/deny access to an Amazon S3 bucket based on an AWS Account number. This is because Amazon S3 ARNs exclude the Account ID and instead use the unique bucket name.

You would need to grant Allow access specifically to each bucket by name.

I have seen this situation before where the requirement was to grant S3 permission to access buckets *only in other accounts*, but not the account owning the IAM User themselves. We could not determine a way to do this without also granting permission to access the "same account" S3 buckets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. Can this be achieved or mimiced through the `condition` block. I updated my question with that?

Comment: According to [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-s3_ResourceAccount), there is a Condition called `s3:ResourceAccount` that "Filters access by the resource owner AWS account ID". However, I don't think that is the Account ID that you want to use.

Comment: I will go through this. Thanks for sharing